# Ways to improve for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a large file and need to match admin ids with users something like this:

```
      TABLE1              TABLE 2
INDEX  V1   IDS            AdmID
  1     A   30               30
  2     U   3                123
  3     U   25               60
  4     U   4                 .
  5     U   5                 .
  6     A   123               .
  7     U   7        
  8     U   8        
  9     U   9        
  10    A   60      
  11    U   26
  12    U    2  
  .     .    .       
  .     .    .       
  .     .    .
```

I want something like this:

```
     COMPLETE TABLE                  
INDEX   V1  IDS   ADMIN_ID         
  1     A   30      30               
  2     U   3       30               
  3     U   25      30              
  4     U   4       30               
  5     U   5       30               
  6     A   123    123               
  7     U   7      123
  8     U   8      123
  9     U   9      123
  10    A   60      60
  11    U   26      60
  12    U    2      60
  .     .    .       .
  .     .    .       .
  .     .    .       .
```

So I wrote this loop, but is taking forever to finish. Any idea of how to use apply() on this situation:

```
ln=10,000;#number of records in the Adm table
TABLE2= index of the adm ids

for (k in 1:ln){
  w<-TABLE2$A_ID[k] #Ids of the adms
  for(i in seq(from=AdmID[k], to=AdmID[k+1], by=1)){
    TABLE1$ADMIN_ID[i]<-w
  }
}
```

Comment: You may use `?match` to get the numeric index or `?merge`, but it is not clear from the loop, what you are trying to do

Comment: which variable is your 'uesrs', and what are you expecting the result to look like?

Comment: Yes! Do use 'match'.

Comment: How do `TABLE 1` and `TABLE 2` relate to each other?

Comment: To get the index I am using `subset(x, is.na(x$V1))`. Not sure how to do it with match. The tables are related by the AdmID.

Comment: Are you sure that the expected output is based on the same TABLE1 as the `30, 6, 10` values in `ADMIN_ID` of expected result is confusing

Comment: So not only are users allowed to share the same Admin_ID, but users can have multiple Admin_IDs too? E.g. the user with ID=30 in your example.
If TABLE2 is the index of the adm ids, perhaps you could join TABLE2 and AdmID (from your loop), consolidate your data. Then a normal join with by INDEX would give you your complete table

Comment: Yeah I did that, I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this. Without a loop maybe using apply().

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question already and got an answer?

Comment: I was getting wrong values for some entries not sure why? I think that has something to do with the file encode but the loop worked although it takes a while to compile.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier if how the mapping is applied by records - `admin$ind`. Cumulative sums are obtained and the mapping table is reversed - `admin`. Then ids can be replaced sequentially - in your case, 12, 9, 5.

```
df <- data.frame(index = c(1:12),
                 v1 = c("A","U","U","U","U","A","U","U","U","A","U","U"),
                 ids = 13:24,
                 admin = 0)
# need rule to assign ids - ind
admin <- data.frame(ind = c(5,4,3), id = c(30,123,60))
# get cumulative sum and reverse admin table
admin$cum <- cumsum(admin$ind)
admin <- admin[nrow(admin):1,]
admin
ind  id cum
3   3  60  12
2   4 123   9
1   5  30   5

# ids will be subsequently updated - 12, 9, 5
for(i in 1:length(admin$cum)) {
  df[as.numeric(row.names(df)) <= admin$cum[i], 4] <- admin$id[i]
}
df
index v1 ids admin
1      1  A  13    30
2      2  U  14    30
3      3  U  15    30
4      4  U  16    30
5      5  U  17    30
6      6  A  18   123
7      7  U  19   123
8      8  U  20   123
9      9  U  21   123
10    10  A  22    60
11    11  U  23    60
12    12  U  24    60
```

Below is another version that uses the individual matching rule, but the cumulative one.

```
df <- data.frame(index = c(1:12),
                 v1 = c("A","U","U","U","U","A","U","U","U","A","U","U"),
                 ids = 13:24)
# need rule to assign ids - ind
admin <- data.frame(ind = c(5,4,3), id = c(30,123,60))

df$admin <- do.call(c, lapply(1:length(admin$ind), function(x) {
  rep(admin$id[x], sum(as.numeric(row.names(df)) <= admin$ind[x]))
}))
```